# Data Entity insert query writes zero instead of correct integer values

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, wcf

I have a data entity object driving a stored procedure that inserts data into a local SQL table. The trouble is that I end up with zeros in my table rather than the integer values I'm pushing through. The rows are created, and the string column is correctly populated. It's a 2-tier project, with a web client front end and an IIS hosted wcf service looking after the data layer. If I use the WCF Test Client, via Visual Studio debugging, to invoke the Insert, the data pushes through perfectly well. If I step through the web client, I can see the correct value assignments within the class object that gets passed to the WCF service call. Something seems to be going wrong between the two and I'm clearly not seeing the wood for the trees on this one.

Here's the data class:

```
[DataContract]
public class CategoryClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Position { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the service:

```
 public Int32 InsertCategory(CategoryClass CategoryItem)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new SQLRepositoryEntities())
            {
                return context.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>("exec InsertCategory @Category, @Description, @Position",
                    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Category", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = CategoryItem.Category },
                    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Description", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = CategoryItem.Description },
                    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Position", SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, Value = CategoryItem.Position }).Single();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Here's the web call to the service:

```
SQLRepositoryItems.RepositoryItems repo = new SQLRepositoryItems.RepositoryItems();
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    CategoryClass category = new CategoryClass();
                    category.Category = row["Name"].ToString();
                    category.Position = Int32.Parse(row["Category_Id"].ToString());
                    category.Description = "";

                    int iOut;
                    bool bOut;

                    try
                    {
                        repo.InsertCategory(category, out iOut, out bOut);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

...and here's the stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCategory]
    @CATEGORY nvarchar(50),
    @DESCRIPTION nvarchar(500),
    @POSITION int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [SQLRepository].[dbo].[RepositoryCategories]
           ([CATEGORY]
           ,[DESCRIPTION]
           ,[POSITION])
     VALUES
           (@CATEGORY,
           @DESCRIPTION, 
           @POSITION)

    DECLARE @ID int
    SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @ID

END
GO
```

Comment: Am I just not seeing the definition of `InsertCategory` that includes two `out` parameters?

Comment: Ah! Thank you! You've pointed me to the problem. In my interface I had the function declared as `[OperationContract]`. Changing it to `[OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat(Style=OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]` fixed the issue. Thanks, @ethorn10

Comment: No problem. While it may seem strange, it is highly recommended that you go ahead and post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I was declaring the method in the interface. My original declaration was:

```
[OperationContract]
Int32 InsertCategory(CategoryClass Category);
```

Changing the declaration to the following corrected the issue:

```
[OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat(Style=OperationFormatStyle.Rpc)]
Int32 InsertCategory(CategoryClass Category);
```